# Retrieving of a file with mongofiles leads to a JSON error

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to retrieve an xml file from my Mongo DB with *mongofiles*. I get a JSON parsing error. Here is an excerpt my terminal:

```
$ mongofiles -d anhalytics get_id 'ObjectId("5e7f56d30800611b17fc66b1")'
 2020-09-15T16:55:33.205+0200   connected to: mongodb://localhost/
 2020-09-15T16:55:33.205+0200   Failed: error parsing id as Extended JSON: invalid JSON number. Position: 18
```

I am using a MongoDB server version: 4.2.9

Here is the record of the target file

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e7f56d30800611b17fc66b1"),
"filename" : "5e7f56d30800611b17fc66b0.tei.xml",
"aliases" : null,
"chunkSize" : NumberLong(261120),
"uploadDate" : ISODate("2020-03-28T13:53:23.708Z"),
"length" : NumberLong(35405),
"contentType" : null,
"md5" : "eeafae907c44b207071ccb6036148808"
```

}

Any idea why I am getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: Double check your command line to make sure your operating system copy/paste has not helpfully replaced the the double-quote `"` with a smart quote `“`

Comment: Done but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The message `error parsing id as Extended JSON` indicates that the mongofiles tool had trouble parsing the id string that was provided on the command line.

That is done in parseOrCreateId function here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/master/mongofiles/mongofiles.go#L330

That function wraps the value from the command line in another string like `{"_id":"%s"}`, so the value actually passed to the `bson.UnmarshalExtJSON` function would have been

```
"{\"_id\":\"ObjectId(\"5e7f56d30800611b17fc66b1\")\"}"
```

Position 18 of that string, as called out in the error message is the quotation mark immediately preceding the hex string.

Comment: Are you then suggesting to upgrade to a newer version of mongo/mongofiles? or is there a way to fix that through modifying the command?

Comment: Try a newer or older version.  If it works there it may be a bug in this version.